# Remove item from array of index unknown

Tags: swiftui

How can I remove an item from my array by clicking on a button?

What I have is a ForEach loop showing all the items in my array

vm is defined here `@StateObject var vm = lister()` so that I can add to it and then show it

Here is my code

```
ForEach(vm.items,id:\.self){item in
                    let i1 = vm.items.firstIndex(where: {$0 == item})
                    HStack{
                        Text("\(item)")
                            
                        Spacer()
                        Button {
                            items.remove(at: i1 ?? 0)
                            print(items)
                            
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "circle")
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                .font(.system(size: 20))
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
                    .cornerRadius(16)
                    .padding(10)
```

but when I click on a circle nothing happens

if I click a lot I eventually get this error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range`

How can I have it so that when I click on an item it get removed from the `lister()` object?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "enumerated()" to get the index in "ForEach" loop

```
ForEach(Array(vm.items.enumerated()),id:\.offset){index, item in
                HStack{
                    Text("\(item)")
                    Spacer()
                    Button {
                        items.remove(at: index)
                        print(items)
                        
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "circle")
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I get this error saying 'cant find items in scope'

Comment: use "vm.items" instead of "items"

Comment: `enumerated` doesn't create indices of items, but rather just their ordinal positions in a sequence. This code will not work, say, with array slices or any other collections with non-zero based indices. Better to either explicitly iterate through indices like @vadian suggested in another asnwer or let the items have unique identifiers and remove them by id, not by the index.

Comment: Since he is using array, it will work in this particular use case without any crash @VadimBelyaev

Answer (score 0):

`ForEach` is a `View` it isn't a for loop, you can't use enumerated or indicies with it, and you certainly shouldn't be using `id:\.self` you'll get major crashes! To use `ForEach` correctly with dynamic data you have to supply it an array of `Identifiable` structs so that it can track the changes. Then you can solve the problem by looking up by the same ID, e.g. something like this:

```
ForEach(model.items){ item in
   HStack{
       Text("\(item.title)")
       Spacer()
       Button {
           model.removeItemWith(id:item.id)
       } label: {
           Image(systemName: "circle")
           .foregroundColor(.black)
           .font(.system(size: 20))
       }
   }

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title = ""
    ...

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = []
    
    func removeItemWith(id: UUID) {
        guard let index = items(where:{ $0.id == id }) else {
           return
        }
        items.remove(at: index)
    }
```